# android - EditText.setTextSize has no effect

Tags: android

i create an Edittext in my code and want to change the textSize, but no matter what i use as argument for `setTextSize`, the text i write looks always the same. Here is my code snippet:

```
float d = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
TableRow.LayoutParams editParams =
            new TableRow.LayoutParams((int)(18*d),
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
EditText editText = new EditText(context);
editText.setTextSize(16*d);
editText.setLayoutParams(editParams);
editText.setPadding(dp, 0, dp, 0);
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
editText.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(com.ginso.mathelernen.R.color.gray_trans));
editText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
InputFilter.LengthFilter filter = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(1);
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {filter});
```

Comment: Do you add this editText to your currentView? Your snippet doesn't mention it

Comment: What is editText.setTextSize(16*d); supposed to do? Try editText.setTextSize(16); or editText.setTextSize(16 * ( getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));

Comment: of course, it's in a TableRow which naturally is in a TableLayout, it is definitely drawn

Comment: @Christian, as i said, i tried arguments with great differences and they didnt change anything, i can use 16 or 100 and it looks all the same

Comment: is your editext into tablerow?

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code? especially the part with the addView(editText)

Comment: sry, i found my error at some other point i change the textsize of all textviews in that tableLayout and forgot that an edittext is also an instance of textview

Comment: `setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,16*d);`

Answer (score 0):

Use this its work in your case

```
    EditText editText = new EditText(context);
    editText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 16*d);
```